# Oracle Apex Region based on PLSQL and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-apex

Oracle Apex 4.2 and Oracle 12c

for e.g.

```
Within apex plsql region I have this code to creating drop down list 
  <button id="Clickme" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
 <br>
 <select name="F01" class="mySelect">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
</select><br>
<select name="F01" class="mySelect">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
</select><br>
<select name="F01" class="mySelect">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
</select><br>
<select name="F01" class="mySelect">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
</select>
```

and so on

On Page load after header I have a process that create localsession as above because default values should come from the db table

for eg.

```
localStorage.setItem('SetDefaults','[{"id":"1","attribute1":"Yes"},{"id":"2","attribute1":"Yes"},{"id":"3","attribute1":"N/A"},{"id":"4","attribute1":"N/A"}]');
```

so when page load all the drop down is null but when click Button then drop down items should display the default values according to the above localStorage data. Reason for  I have 5 columns on the page and each column has same as column 1 but should display different data according to the button.

Any help please?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the problem that you have or what error you get?

Answer (score 0):

-- some html code
-- // dropdown list class  'Listcls'

```
<select name="F03" class="selectlist Listcls " "="" size="1" data-obs="1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
      </select>
```

-- javascript code to get a default value when click button however I can't fiqure how to display the json value when click button.

```
// Button class  'BtnCls'

    $('.BtnCls').on('click', function() {
      var vdef = [{"id":"1","attribute1":"Yes"},{"id":"2","attribute1":"Yes"},{"id":"3","attribute1":"N/A"},{"id":"4","attribute1":"N/A"},{"id":"5","attribute1":"N/A"},
      {"id":"6","attribute1":"N/A"},{"id":"7","attribute1":"N/A"},];
      var vdefault =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vdef));
      for (var i = 0; i < vdefault.length; i++) {
            var obs = vdefault[i].attribute1;
    // dropdown list class  'Listcls'

      //  $('.Listcls').css('background-color', 'grey'); -- working for testing

         }

});
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to display the JSON value when click the button so it drop down options should be displayed according to the default value.